# awk: is there a way to filter non-matching regex?

Tags: regex, awk

In certain cases I use awk this way:

```
% some_command | awk /regex/
```

since it does not buffer its output and I can get some_command's output right away. There's a way to do it with grep as well (using --line-buffered I think) but I don't have this version of grep on the system I work on. So awk does the job.

However some times I'd like to filter non-matching regex (i.e. like grep's -v option). Is there a way to do that with awk?

Comment: awk buffers output too. maybe you just got lucky some time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
some_command | awk '!/regex/'
```

The `!` means "not," so this selects lines that don't match `regex`.